# Wvdial.conf dial errors. Raspberry Pi Model B Huawei E1820 3G Modem

Tags: linux, modem, mobile, wvdial

Linux is kicking my butt.
I have attempted to use `wvdial` for the first time to get 3G working on my Raspberry Pi, but things have not gone as expected. First of all, when I do a simple

```
sudo wvdialconf
```

The scan gives me the following message:

[image]

Ok. Probably not the best start I can get because of the errors on lines:

```
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 -- ERROR
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 &C1 -- ERROR
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 &D2 -- ERROR
```

I figured that these errors could probably be the reason of the failure of my later attempt to use `wvdial`, which gives me the output as such:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "internet"
AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "internet"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "internet"
AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "internet"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "internet"
AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "internet"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
```

To provide some background on my configurations:
My `wvdial.conf` looks like this:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Phone = *99#
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Username = username
Password = password
Baud = 9600
[Dialer E1820]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "internet"
Stupid Mode = 1
Phone = *99#
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Username = username
Carrier Check = no
Password = password
Baud = 9600
```

and my `dmesg` logs look as such:
[image]

From these outputs, I infer (or possibly wrongly assumed) that my Huawei E1820 has indeed been turned into a modem and is ready for `wvdial` dialing.

Additional Info:
The SIM Card I'm using has been disabled of SIM_PIN and is bought from Chunghwa Telecom, a major telecom company located in Taiwan.

***Updated***
Hi all, I have tried changing my configs in the `/etc/wvdial.conf` file and now it looks as such:

```
[Dialer E1820]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/gsmmodem
Baud = 460800
Username = username
Carrier Check = no
Password = password
```

Now when I run `wvdial`, I get such error:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ 0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATD*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATD*99#
ERROR
--> Invalid dial command.
--> Disconnecting at Sat Aug 20 08:53:35 2016
```

I suspect that the reason for this is either:

- the modem is not working as expected, or
- the parameter Phone in the `/etc/wvdial.conf` file is not properly assigned.

Hope I get this to work. Any ideas out there?

Comment: (1) I edited your question to improve the formatting.  Please check that I didn’t damage the content (and fix it if I did).  (2) [Please don’t post images of text.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm new as you can see. Still looking for answers :), any clues?